# Hello, Did anyone already built a plugin using V2.0 Flex-project-template?

Tags: flexbox, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-flex

I am already done with all the steps mentioned here - https://github.com/twilio-professional-services/flex-project-template. However, i need some guidance or the examples on how to use and call the pre-built and custom functions/actions in Flex-project-template.
Thanks in advance.

https://github.com/twilio-professional-services/flex-project-template

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to the project's root folder in your terminal, run the 'twilio flex:plugins:start' function, and you're done. However, I recommend that you read the 'Readme' file included in the project's documentation.